# how to do equality comparision in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var a = 5;
var b = 5; 
var c = 5;
var d = 5;
```

What could be robust and quick way to compare if they hold same value in plain JavaScript then return true else false.

```
function compare(){
   var 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return a == b && b == c && c == d;
```

Comment: thanks i had this in my mind before but i think this is the only way. Cheers

Comment: Another "possible" way: `return Math.max.apply(0,[a,b,c,d]) == a` NO NO NO

Comment: @elclanrs WAT? `Math.max.apply(0, [5, 4, 3, 2]) == 5`

Comment: LOL. Long day. I tried with higher numbers only, foolish of me. Ingore!

Comment: lol that can't be more quick then Kolink BitWise && and == just thinking how to make it generic i.e. independt of number of arguments passed.

Answer (score 2):

you can check this by `a==b` or by  `a===b`

```
return a === b && b === c && c === d;
```

Comment: Yay, a good answer! Seriously, I swear these "easy" questions draw out all the stupidest answers... It's nice to see someone actually get it right. +1 to you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(a,b,c,d) {
       return a == b && b == c && c == d;
}
```

Comment: The hell? You'd rather write `compare(a,b)` than `a==b`? And... Just... WHAT? "if a statement is true return true else return false"... why not just return the statement?

Answer (score 1):

A quick comparison would be `a === (b&c&d)`

A generic comparison function could be:

```
function allEqual(){
  if (arguments.length<2){
   return true;
  }
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  return args.filter(
          function(a,i){return a === this[i ? i-1 : 0]},args)
         .length === args.length;
}
//usage
allEqual(7,6,5,4);                 //=> false
allEqual(5,5,5,5);                 //=> true
allEqual(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1); //=> true
allEqual(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1); //=> false
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the javascript equality test is
If a==b then
   something;

Comment: I was answering the questioninthe heading which was...........How to do equality in javascript